# How to filter shop orders by the order price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

my shop have 3 products with fixed prices ( 0$ , 18$ and 36$ ).

im trying to make a filter in the admin panel that will give me all the orders by a fixed price.

this is what i have tried so far :

```
/**
 * Add price bulk filter for orders
 */
function add_filter_by_payment_price_orders() {
    global $typenow;
    if ( 'shop_order' === $typenow ) {
        $amount_array = array(0,18,36);
        ?>
        <select name="_shop_order_payment_price" id="dropdown_shop_order_payment_price">
            <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'All Payment prices', 'text-domain' ); ?></option>
            <?php foreach ( $amount_array as $key => $amount ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr( isset( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_price'] ) ? selected( $key, $_GET['_shop_order_payment_price'], false ) : '' ); ?>>
                <?php echo $amount ; ?>
            </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'add_filter_by_payment_price_orders', 99 );

/**
 * Process bulk filter order for payment method
 *
 */
function add_filter_by_payment_price_orders_query( $vars ) {
    global $typenow;
    if ( 'shop_order' === $typenow && isset( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_price'] ) ) {
        $vars['meta_key']   = 'total';
        $vars['meta_value'] = wc_clean( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_price'] );
    }
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'add_filter_by_payment_price_orders_query', 99 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Add price bulk filter for orders
 */
function add_filter_by_payment_price_orders() {
    global $typenow;
    if ( 'shop_order' === $typenow ) {
        $amount_array = array(0,18,36);
        ?>
        <select name="_shop_order_payment_price" id="dropdown_shop_order_payment_price">
            <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'All Payment prices', 'text-domain' ); ?></option>
            <?php foreach ( $amount_array as $key => $amount ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $amount); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr( isset( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_price'] ) ? selected( $key, $_GET['_shop_order_payment_price'], false ) : '' ); ?>>
                <?php echo $amount ; ?>
            </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'add_filter_by_payment_price_orders', 99 );

/**
 * Process bulk filter order for payment method
 *
 */
function add_filter_by_payment_price_orders_query( $vars ) {
    global $typenow;
    if ( 'shop_order' === $typenow && isset( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_price'] ) ) {
        $vars['meta_key']   = '_order_total';
        $vars['meta_value'] = wc_clean( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_price'] );
    }
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'add_filter_by_payment_price_orders_query', 99 );
```

Comment: the right meta key was " _order_total "